# from package import module VS import package.module as moduleName

Tags: python, python-module

```
.
├── bank
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── currency.py
│   └── user.py
└── script.py
```

Suppose this is my folder structure.

Is there any difference between

```
from bank import user
```

and

```
import bank.user as user
```

inside of `script.py`?

As far as I can tell, both import the `user` module available as `user` in the global namespace. Is there any difference?

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference - for an in depth discussion on the different styles of imports see this post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function

Comment: @TLOwater Thanks, the chosen answer there definitely was a good read.

Comment: Although there is semantically no difference I always wonder why someone uses the `import … as` variant and the _not_ renaming the module but repeating the module name again. Seems redundant.

Answer (score 3):

There's not difference in this and I think it's bad design why Python even allows this. Another inconsistency is that while for modules and packages, both ways are allowed, but for identifiers only one is allowed. Eg

`from bank.user import user_func`

is ok but

`import bank.user.user_func as user_func`

gives an error that user_func is not a module and bank.user is not a package.